# Fork a fresh Linux process with all attributes reset. Attributes are fds, signal handlers, and everything else in the task_struct

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, fork, clone, file-descriptor

**TL;DR** How do I `fork` a fresh process without inheriting all the attributes (file descriptors, memory maps, working directory, fancy new kernel features, ...) from the parent?

---

The two traditional ways on a Linux system to create new processes are [fork](https://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) and [clone](https://linux.die.net/man/2/clone). The libc wrappers are very thin wrappers around the raw syscalls [fork](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/fork.c#L2063) and [clone](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/fork.c#L2100). Having a look at all other [syscalls](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) (disregarding vfork), no other system call seems to spawn a new process.

For this question, lets define *new* process as the creation of a new [task_struct](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/sched.h#L483) in the kernel.

Question 1) Is it correct that `fork`, `vfork`, and `clone` are the only system calls which create a new process? (Considering kernel 4.x)

A process has attributes, namely everything which is stored in the `task_struct`. I selected the name "attributes" as it is used in the [execve](https://linux.die.net/man/2/execve) man page. Attributes include file descriptors, signal handlers, seccomp context, capabilities, memory mappings, the complete virtual memory setup ... It is a decade-old problem that Linux programs may leak file descriptors into their children. But since `fork` and `clone` copy the `task_struct` of the parent, more than just file descriptors are leaked: namely everything.

Let's define a *fresh* process as a new process where all process attributes are not inherited from the parent but sane default values are chosen. For example, pwd is the home of the user, no filedescriptors except 0,1,2 are inherited, there are no mapped memory areas, a fresh stack is used, ...

Question 2) Is it possible to get a *fresh* process on Linux with just one system call?

Question 3) Is it possible to get a *fresh* process on some BSD or POSIX system with just one system call?

The intention behind my question is that I don't want to leak anything to my child. But Linux adds new attributes to the `task_struct` from time to time. I don't want to clean up in userspace because that cleanup would depend on the kernel version. Also, I want to create a fresh process from a high-level language, for example Haskell, where the runtime (which is not under my control) has polluted the parent process with many attributes. This also depends on the version of the language runtime. In short, I don't know which attributes are used and which attributes need to be cleaned in userspace.

My idea of a fresh process sounds dangerous from a security point of view: Linux relies on the concept that seccomp filters and capability bounding sets are always passed to the children. That means, a process cannot increase its permissions by creating new process. A *fresh* process would subvert this security concept.

Question 4) What is the best way to get a *fresh* process on Linux (possibly with some cleanup in the userspace)?

Question 5) Are there different answers to Question 4 depending on whether I want to `execve` in the new fresh process?

Comment: A lot of what you want to do can be done with the `unshare` system call.

Comment: I didn't mean namespaces (or containers, if we go one step further). But thanks, good point! We can get fresh namespaces with `unshare` (or the corresponding `clone` flags). But this also gets to the essence of my question: How do we clean, close, unshare, ... in a way that we get a fresh process even if a new kernel adds new attributes/namespaces.

Comment: Do not mix **shared** attributes and **inherited** ones. Reseting flag `CLONE_FILES` in `clone()` or setting it in `unshare()` call prevents *sharing* of file descriptors, but leave them *inherited*, like `fork()` does.

Answer (score 1):

> Question 4) What is the best way to get a fresh process on Linux (possibly with some cleanup in the userspace)?

One of the way is to create a special process at the very beginning of the program (before opening files, changing signal handlers and so on). Then you may use this process as a **factory**, asking it to create new processes for you.

Because factory process is created at the very beginning, it will be "fresh process", and processes created by it will also be "fresh".

But this way you cannot overcome security aspects. From the other side, security is needed exactly for the purpose that it cannot be overcome.

By the way, Linux kernel itself uses special thread ("kthreadd") for create kernel threads.

Disadvantages of this approach is that new processes will have same start function. But you want stack of the new process to be "fresh", don't you?

> Question 5) Are there different answers to Question 4 depending on whether I want to execve in the new fresh process?

`execve()` by itself creates nearly fresh process. Literally, it inherits from the parent only opened file descriptors. But I know no simple way for *automatically* close these descriptors in the child.

Comment: `excecve` does exactly the opposite. From the man page `All process attributes are preserved during an execve(),  except  the following:...` If it were just fds, we could mark them all with `FD_CLOEXEC` and everything would be fine. Unfortunately, we leak more :(

I like the fork-factory idea, but it assumes that the initial parent where we start from is *fresh* (which may not always be true).

Comment: Among attributes you have listed explicitely in the question post, only opened file descriptors and security-related attributes are preserved during `execve()`. If you don't know about these attributes, why you should care to not preserve them? As you could mark all opened file descriptors with `FD_CLOEXEC`, you have relatively full control over the program. In that case placing additional `fork()` at the very beginning shouldn't be a problem.